# Create PDF file in WP7 using C#

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to develop small application for WINDOWS PHONE7 in which User enters Transaction details eg.Transaction Amount and Bank code. 
I want to create new PDF file and write this data in it.
I tried adding iTextSharp.dll but is gives Error: Reference cannot be added it Windows Phone project will work with Windows Phone assemblies.
Please suggest other way or assemblies available for it.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this on the phone. So don't do it on the phone. Do it on a server in a web service. You can deliver the PDF back to the phone if that is its final destination, or email it directly from the server.

Comment: Thanks for reply..! I will try using web service.But is their any paid third party tool or library available.

Comment: There are several. SQL Server Reporting Services can render as PDF, and for lighter weight stuff there is assorted options ranging from freeware to stonkingly expensive. Type "pdf dll c#" into Google for a selection of options with sample implementations.